# calculate hours difference between two dates without holidays in php

Tags: php

I have made a code to calculate the difference in hours between two dates, but I have a problem, holidays are still being calculated.

i want to calculate the difference without following the holidays

here is my code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$start_date  = date_create("2023-08-18 00:00:00");
$end_date = date_create("2023-08-21 00:00:00");
$different  = date_diff( $start_date, $end_date );
$day = $different->d;
$hour = $different->h;
$minute = $different->i;
        
if($hour < 10){
    $this_hour = "0".$hour;
} else {
    $this_hour = $hour;
}
        
if($minute < 10){
    $this_minute = "0".$minute;
} else {
    $this_minute = $minute;
}
        
if($day < 1){
    $result = $this_hour.":".$this_minute;
} elseif($day >= 1) {
    $total_hour = ($day * 24) + $this_hour;
    $result = $total_hour.":".$this_minute;
}

echo $result;
//Outpput is = 72:00
```

i have tried the code above, but i want the result not to count holidays. Thanks.

Comment: How are you defining holidays? Are they stored in a data structure somewhere? Also what research have you done? I would be astonished if no-one has solved this problem before in php.

Comment: defines a holiday between the $awal and $akhir variables. Can it?

Comment: Maybe you can add an array with the holidays stored in them. Iterate through each day within the date range and check if it's a holiday. If it's not a holiday, add 24 hours to the duration for that day. After iterating through all days, add the remaining hours and minutes from the original calculation, though adding holidays may be lengthy process.

Comment: Religious or linguistic variable names makes it difficult for me to help actually.

Comment: @AlokMarathe I've tried it, but it still doesn't work, can you give an example with the code?

Comment: @nice_dev I'm sorry for this, I'm from Indonesia, therefore the variables are from my language

Comment: @mahen can you please tell me what those variables mean if you can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$awal  = date_create("2023-08-18 00:00:00");
$akhir = date_create("2023-08-21 00:00:00");

// Array of holidays
$holidays = array("2023-08-19"); // Example holiday. Add more dates as needed.

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$periods = new DatePeriod($awal, $interval, $akhir);

$holidayHours = 0;
foreach ($periods as $period) {
    if (in_array($period->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) {
        $holidayHours += 24; // Exclude 24 hours for each holiday
    }
}

$diff  = date_diff($awal, $akhir);
$hariNya = $diff->d;
$jamNya = $diff->h;
$menitNya = $diff->i;

if($jamNya < 10){
    $jamNya2 = "0".$jamNya;
} else {
    $jamNya2 = $jamNya;
}

if($menitNya < 10){
    $menitNya2 = "0".$menitNya;
} else {
    $menitNya2 = $menitNya;
}

if($hariNya < 1){
    $durasi = $jamNya2.":".$menitNya2;
} elseif($hariNya >= 1) {
    $gg = $hariNya * 24;
    $ff = $gg+$jamNya2 - $holidayHours; // Subtract holiday hours from total
    $durasi = $ff.":".$menitNya2;
}

echo $durasi;
```

I have added this `$holidays = array("2023-08-19");` for the example. You have to add your holiday days in this array.